# VS Code Apex Error

Tags: vs-code

I have the Salesforce VS Code Extension Pack installed, and I keep getting errors popping up in the Output tab on VS Code. It's very annoying and I can't get them to go away!

[image: Output error]

Is there any way to fix this, or turn it off?

```
apex.jorje.semantic.compiler.CodeUnit traverse
INFO: unexpected error during apex MemberResolveVisitor:
Class body hit character limit 10000
```

Comment: Wat API version is your class saved in? The apex class character limit should be 1000.000 characters for the newer API versions. 10.000 sounds really small.

Comment: The API version is 48.0

Comment: That's a strange error to get. The only thing I can come up with is running sfdx update, but I doubt that will help.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: You might want to add the error message ad verbum in your question. That way, if someone else is also running into this issue they can find your question.

Comment: You could also try opening a github issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/328